# How to set focus to the webForm

Tags: c#, winforms

```
else if (answer is TextAnswer)
    {
        this.Sourcecode.AppendLine("\t\t\t\t<textarea id='" + id + "' name='" + id + "' value='' style='position: absolute; "
                                   + "top: " + top + "px; left: " + left + "px; height: " + height + "px; width: " + width + "px; "
                                   + "visibility:hidden; z-index: 2; resize: none;'></textarea>");
```

This line of code creates a TextBox control on my web form but the problem is there is no focus set on it and I want to set focus.

How to do this?

This line of code works perfectly fine, I mean when I click on my web form it creates a control. Now when I click on it, it creates a control to write something then I have to click on it again , so i just want that when I click focus should be there.

Comment: is that the entirety of your code?

Comment: try this : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_autofocus.asp

Comment: What version of windows will this code be running on? What version of .NET are you using?

Answer (score 1):

try putting this after the code you show. This assumes you can see the Id.

```
id.Focus();
```

If you id has not been inserted into the DOM yet you will not find the element, then another solution could be to use javascript to do the job.

```
var script = "<script>document.getElementById("+id+").focus();</script>";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), id, script, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `autofocus` attribute in `textarea`. Remember that this will required HTML5 support. It seems like you are using the default web control in your C# application?

```
this.Sourcecode.AppendLine("\t\t\t\t<textarea autofocus id='" + id + "' name='" + id + "' value='' style='position: absolute; "
                                   + "top: " + top + "px; left: " + left + "px; height: " + height + "px; width: " + width + "px; "
                                   + "visibility:hidden; z-index: 2; resize: none;'></textarea>");
```

Check the example below:
http://jsfiddle.net/9m0tctzg/

Another alternative is to inject some JS in there, if the above code is not an option.

```
<script> document.getElementById('idhere').focus(); </script>
```

Comment: this.Sourcecode.AppendLine("<script>\t\t\t\tdocument.getElementById (" + id + ").focus();</script>");  actually already added this line of code earlier but seems not working.